# error as metioned below

Tags: java, hibernate

There is a employee class which has a set of languages known by him.

> error :Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException:
>   Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: Employee_Table,
>   for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(languages)]

Employee.java

```
    package Mapping.Collection.Set;

    import java.util.*;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Employee_Table")
    public class Employee {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int empId;
        @Column(name="EMP_NAME",nullable=false)
        private String empName;
        public int getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }
        public void setEmpId(int empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }
        public String getEmpName() {
            return empName;
        }
        public void setEmpName(String empName) {
            this.empName = empName;
        }
        public int getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }
        public void setSalary(int salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
        private int salary;


        @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
        @JoinColumn(name="Languages_Known")
        private Set<String> languages=new HashSet<>();

        public Set<String> getLanguages() {
            return languages;
        }
        public void setLanguages(Set<String> languages) {
            this.languages = languages;
        }




    }


    TestMain.java
    package Mapping.Collection.Set;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

    public class TestMain {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Employee emp=new Employee();
            emp.setEmpId(1);
            emp.setEmpName("Shrini Jaiswal");
            emp.setSalary(10000000);
            emp.getLanguages().add("Hindi");
            emp.getLanguages().add("English");
            SessionFactory factory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session=factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();  
            tx.begin();
            session.save(emp);
            tx.commit();
                session.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Missing a @CollectionTable

Comment: To increase your chance of getting answers [Write a title that summarizes the specific problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate Annotation, @ElementCollection is the feature which gets the columns values from another table without mapping two tables.

You should have list of Language in another table, then only you use like this..

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="languages", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="empId"))
private Set<String> languages;
```

Please [read this](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/elementcollection_hibernate_annotation)  post for more info.